# Transitions in D3 - Duplicate bubbles instead of transitioning bubbles

Tags: d3.js, transition, bubble-chart

I'm trying to create something similar to this example: [Wealth and Health of Nations](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/nations/):

[image]

My data comes from a JSON file, just like the example, but when I add the transitions, I'm getting duplicate bubbles. Instead of the bubble transitioning from point A to point B I'm getting 2 bubbles (one for point A, one for point B). Generally speaking, the transition is not able to differentiate between 2 data points for the same bubble or 2 separate bubbles.

Looking at the example, I'm missing the interpolate and bisect functions. I haven't been able to grasp how they work and what exactly i'm doing wrong. Is this what's causing the problem in my graph?

Also, can someone give me an example on how bisectors and interpolate works in d3?

Code:

```
 g = d3.select("#animation")
                .append("svg")
                .attr("width", width)
                .attr("height", height);

      x_extent = [0, 100];
      x_scale = d3.scale.linear().domain(x_extent).range([margin + 20, width - 30]);

      y_extent = [0, 60];
      y_scale = d3.scale.linear().domain(y_extent).range([height - margin, margin]);


      r_scale = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, d3.max(jsondata, function (d) { return d.MSVMMboe; })]).range([2, 30]);

      g.selectAll("circle").data(jsondata, function (d) { return d.EffectiveDate; }).enter().append("circle")
                      .attr("cx", function (d) { return x_scale(d.PercentageComplete * 100) })
                      .attr("cy", function (d) { return y_scale(d.GPoS * 100) })
                      .attr("r", function (d) { return r_scale(d.MSVMMboe) })
                      .attr("stroke", "blue")
                      .attr("stroke-width", 1)
                      .attr("opacity", 0.6)
                      .attr("fill", "red");


                      //add transition

                      g.selectAll("circle").data(jsondata, function (d) { return d.EffectiveDate; })
                      .transition()
                      .duration(1000);
```

Comment: Sounds like you're adding new elements during the transition, i.e. you have something like `.data(...).append(...).transition(...)`. Remove the `.append(...)` or whatever from there. Without showing us the actual code it's impossible to tell where exactly you went wrong though.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told the transition what you want to change. You need to add some attribute changes for example. Have a look at the d3 website for examples and tutorials.

Comment: Initially i had the following:
   g.selectAll("circle")
    .data(jsondata, function (d) { return d.EffectiveDate; })
    .transition()
    .duration(1000)
    .attr("cx", function (d) { return x_scale(d.PercentageComplete * 100) })
     .attr("cy", function (d) { return y_scale(d.GPoS * 100) })

What i want the bubble to do is to go to the next (cx, cy) point but it is not recognizing which one is the next point to go. The next point have bubble name and bubble id in common and it has a date that distinguishes it EX: bubble A date 10-01-2010 ; bubble B date 12-31-2010.

Comment: I had created a simple demo with 2 different datasets and that worked fine cause i had set up the transition from a point in dataset1 to a point in datase2 but since i switched to the json file, all points are in a single "dataset" and that's what the transition fails to recognize now

Comment: There's no magic in d3 -- the transition doesn't recognize anything, you have to tell it what to do. You have to identify the next point and set attributes accordingly.

Comment: I understand that, that's what i'm having trouble with, I'm not sure how to identify the next point within the dataset and tell D3 to use that point. I tried using a different key in .data(dataset, key) but that didn't do it.

Comment: From your description it sounds like you need to match on name or id instead of `EffectiveDate`. The basic pattern is that you select all the data with the first date and draw the bubbles. Then select the data with the second date and make the same call again, except instead of `.enter()` you call `.transition()`.